# Own class can't convert string to integer

Tags: vb.net

https://imgur.com/a/gaXh4
Ok so I have a problem a really weird problem. So I created a new class which is a new type of TextBox. It keeps track of the objects created from it with the help of a list but. This all works, with for each I can get all objects of the class but when I want to convert the string from the TextBox into a integer I can't do it because it thinks its not convertable eventhought the string only consists out of number symbols

Code for Button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'TextBox1.Text = CInt(SumTextBox1.Text) + CInt(SumTextBox2.Text) 


    For Each item As SumTextBox In SumTextBox.sumList
        Dim textItem As SumTextBox = item
        TextBox1.Text = CInt(TextBox1.Text) + CInt(textItem.Text)
    Next
End Sub



Public Class SumTextBox
Inherits TextBox
Public Shared sumList As New List(Of SumTextBox)


Sub New()
    Size = New Size(90, 10)
    sumList.Add(Me)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I get an System.InvalidCastException exceptiont the weird thing about is that all characters I entered are numbers

Comment: What is the full message of the exception?

Comment: Sorry that you needed to wait I had to download the english language pack. xD It is saying 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Convert.toInt32(TextBox1.Text)` and the same for textitem.text

Comment: No still doesn't work :/ now the exception is An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: input string has the wrong format.

Comment: What happens if you remove the textitem cast? Does it run?

Comment: Oh well that was the solution, I wasn't paying attention on the resultbox :s thanks for your help ^^